# Audio problems after clean 20.04 install, no sound output device

Tags: drivers, 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 (dual boot) and cannot get any audio out of the system. I've tried the headphone port on my computer, the headphone port on my HDMI monitor and my audio interface (Tascam US-122 MKII). All of them work in Windows but none in Ubuntu.

When going to the system sound settings no devices appear, but the sound cards are recognised.

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                     HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfcf60000 irq 74
1 [MKII           ]: USB-Audio - US122 MKII
                     TASCAM US122 MKII at usb-0000:03:00.0-1, high speed
2 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                     HD-Audio Generic at 0xfca00000 irq 76

$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: MKII [US122 MKII], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
 Subdevices: 1/1
 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
26:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1002:aaf0]
   Subsystem: Sapphire Technology Limited Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590] [1da2:aaf0]
   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
   Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
--
28:00.4 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1022:1487]
   Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller [1462:9b86]
   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
   Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

When running `alsamixer` I get the following results:

```
┌────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.2.2 ──────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HDA ATI HDMI                                   F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: ATI R6xx HDMI                                  F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All             F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: S/PDIF [Off]                                   Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│              ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐               │
│              │MM│     │MM│     │MM│     │MM│     │MM│     │MM│               │
│              └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘               │
│           < S/PDIF >S/PDIF 1 S/PDIF 2 S/PDIF 3 S/PDIF 4 S/PDIF 5             │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.2.2 ──────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: US122 MKII                                     F1:  Help               │
│ Chip:                                                F2:  System information │
│ View: F3: Playback  F4: Capture  F5: All             F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item:                                                Esc: Exit               │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│                                                                              │
│                This sound device does not have any controls.                 │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── AlsaMixer v1.2.2 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Card: HD-Audio Generic                                                                                         F1:  Help               │
│ Chip: Realtek ALC892                                                                                           F2:  System information │
│ View: F3:[Playback] F4: Capture  F5: All                                                                       F6:  Select sound card  │
│ Item: Master [dB gain: -6,00]                                                                                  Esc: Exit               │
│   ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐     ┌──┐                       ┌──┐     ┌──┐   │
│   │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │▒▒│     │  │     │  │                       │  │     │  │   │
│   ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     └──┘     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     ├──┤     └──┘   Enabled  Disabled   ├──┤     └──┘   │
│   │OO│     │OO│     │OO│     │MM│              │OO│     │OO│     │OO│     │OO│     │MM│                                │MM│            │
│   └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘              └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘     └──┘                                └──┘            │
│    78    100<>100 100<>100   0<>0     0<>0   100<>100   100      100    100<>100   0<>0     0<>0                       0<>0     0<>0   │
│< Master >Headphon  Front   Front Mi Front Mi Surround  Center    LFE      Side     Line   Line Boo Auto-Mut Loopback Rear Mic Rear Mic │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I tried using/disabling/reinstalling ALSA, PulseAudio, Timidity and Pavucontrol with plenty of reboots in between. I've noticed a couple results which I'll share.

`pulseaudio` doesn't function properly:

```
$pulseaudio -k
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such file or directory

$killall pulseaudio
pulseaudio: no process found

$ pulseaudio --start
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.

$ pulseaudio -v
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 13.99.1
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 54967f8432fa4e459792d2f0c0991d8a.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /run/user/1000/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/roelof/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
W: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: System supports high resolution timers
I: [pulseaudio] cpu-x86.c: CPU flags: CMOV MMX SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 MMXEXT 
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] sconv_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized conversions.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_orc.c: Initialising ORC optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/roelof/.config/pulse/54967f8432fa4e459792d2f0c0991d8a-device-volumes'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-device-restore" (index: #0; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-stream-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/roelof/.config/pulse/54967f8432fa4e459792d2f0c0991d8a-stream-volumes'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-stream-restore" (index: #1; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/roelof/.config/pulse/54967f8432fa4e459792d2f0c0991d8a-card-database'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-card-restore" (index: #2; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-augment-properties" (index: #3; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-port-available" (index: #4; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-connect" (index: #5; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)main.c: error: failed to import hw:1 use case configuration -2
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)main.c: error: failed to import US122 MKII use case configuration -2
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-ucm.c: UCM not available for card US122 MKII
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:1: No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:1: No such file or directory
Killed
```

Furthermore I also noticed `pavucontrol` doesn't work. Whenever I open the app using `$puvucontrol` I get a message "Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait..." in the volume control window.

I've been trying tutorials and guides for hours but I'm a bit new to Ubuntu. Does anyone know what else I can try?

Computer specs:

- MSI B450-A Pro Max,
- AMD Ryyzen 5 3600,
- RX 580 8 GB,
- SSD,
- 2xHDD,
- 32 GB RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the kernal to v5.11 solved most of the problems for me. I am seeing outputs and i can hear audio.
I do still have the occasional shirping high pitched noise when using my Tascam US-MKII interface. Plugging my headphones in the hdmi output solves this problem.